# How to share Hashmap between threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I am getting empty hashmap when I print it, what's the best approach to Share Static volatile variable between threads?

```
class RunnableDemo implements Runnable {
      int i;
      RunnableDemo(int i) {
          i = i;
      }

      public void run(){
         finResult.put("value"+str(i), 1);
      } 

      public void start () {
          System.out.println("Starting " );
          if (t == null) {
             t = new Thread (this);
             t.start ();
      }
}

public class TestThread {
    public static volatile ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> finResult = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for(int i=0; i < 4; i++){
            RunnableDemo task = new RunnableDemo(i);
            executor.execute(task);
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }
    System.out.println(TestThread.finResult);
}
```

`System.out.println(TestThread.finResult);` This should print the finResult with all the values from threads.

Comment: The answer is "you probably shouldn't". What's the intended use? Seems like a `CyclicBarrier` might be the thing.

Comment: I just want updated `finResult` from all threads. Instead of returning any value I am pushing values into global shared variable.

Comment: `parallelStream()`?

Comment: I have two options 1 ) Return value from threads (which I don't know how to do it )    and 2) Have `global variable` which gets modified by threads using `sync` block. I am focusing on second option.

Comment: Could you post the complete compilable code? What is the "start()" method for? Furthermore, i=i makes no sense in the constructor and what is str(i) for ?

Comment: The code as written has several undefined references - specifically, finResult and t.  Could you modify your example to something that compiles and runs?  I suspect the issue is that the production code is referencing a different finResult variable than the test code is printing out, but can't tell for sure from the code provided.